# How to get a "item" if I created it on the code

Tags: vb.net, variables, button, listbox, call

```
    Public WithEvents newListBox As Windows.Forms.ListBox
        newListBox = New Windows.Forms.ListBox
    newListBox.Name = "ListBox" & i
    newListBox.Height = 44
    newListBox.Width = 250
    newListBox.Top = 10 + i * 50
    newListBox.Left = 150
    newListBox.Tag = i
    Me.Controls.Add(newListBox)
```

So I created a button that create a listbox and I set a name for each listbox while created.
This listbox are filled with files that I select, but how can I get the values from a especified listbox like.

```
For Each nome In ListBox1.Items
```

...

If I cant call ListBox1 on the main code cuz its not created yet.

So what should I do ? How can I get the right listbox insted of the last one created.

Comment: Do you want to know which is the current Item selected in one of the ListBox Controls you have created? Or all the strings (or FileInfo?) a specific ListBox contains? Which ListBox?

Comment: You can retrieve it from the form controls collection.

Comment: How are you trying to retrieve the correct ListBox, the tag field?  The name?  You should be able to accomplish either via LINQ.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that the compiler can't know about ListBoxi at compile time. It is not created until runtime.

```
Friend WithEvents newListBox As ListBox

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Static i As Integer = 1
    newListBox = New ListBox
    newListBox.Name = "ListBox" & i
    newListBox.Height = 44
    newListBox.Width = 250
    newListBox.Top = 10 + i * 50
    newListBox.Left = 150
    newListBox.Tag = i
    Me.Controls.Add(newListBox)
    i += 1
End Sub


Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim listBoxi = TryCast(Controls.Find("ListBox1", True).FirstOrDefault(), ListBox)
    For Each item In listBoxi.Items

    Next
End Sub
```